# Call the lap function in timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I've been bothering on this problem for a while now, I have a timer that has 4 buttons start, stop, reset and lap, when I call `Stopwatch.start();`, `Stopwatch.stop();` or `Stopwatch.reset();` it works just fine but when I'm trying to call `Stopwatch.lap();` it does not work !

I had the answer before but now I have a new computer and things like that and I can't call the function. The console says "Uncaught TypeError: Stopwatch.lap is not a function" and I can't find the problem.

Here is my code:

```
var Stopwatch = {
init: function(elem, options) {

    var timer       = createTimer(),
            startButton = createButton("start", start),
        stopButton  = createButton("stop", stop),
        resetButton = createButton("reset", reset),
            lapButton   = createButton("lap", lap),
            lapSpan     = createTimer(),
        offset,
        clock,
        interval;

    options = options || {};
    options.delay = options.delay || 1;

    elem.appendChild(timer);
    elem.appendChild(startButton);
    elem.appendChild(stopButton);
    elem.appendChild(resetButton);
    elem.appendChild(lapButton);
    elem.appendChild(lapSpan);

    reset();

    function createTimer() {
        return document.createElement("span");
    }

    function createButton(action, handler) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "#" + action;
        a.innerHTML = action;
        a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            handler();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return a;
    }

    function start() {
        if (!interval) {
            offset = Date.now();
            interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
        }
    }

    function stop() {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
    }

    function lap() {
            lapSpan.innerHTML=timer.innerHTML;
        }

    function reset() {
        clock = 0;
        render(0);
                lap();
    }

    function update() {
        clock += delta();
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        timer.innerHTML = clock / 1000;
    }

    function delta() {
        var now = Date.now(),
        d = now - offset;

        offset = now;
        return d;
    }

        this.getTime=function() {
            return clock;
        }

    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;
    this.reset = reset;
}
};
var elems;
window.onload=function() {
   elems = document.getElementsByClassName("basic");
   for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
       Stopwatch.init(elems[i]);
   }
}
```

And I need to call the lap function when I press a specified key and it looks like this:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
    Stopwatch.start();

} else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
    Stopwatch.lap();

}
};
```

I am most familiar with JavaScript and jQuery in this project but I also know HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I supose you need to add `this.lap = lap;` also in the end of that class/object...

Comment: OMG Thank you so much, post the answer and I'll mark it as the answer ! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did define the function inside the class/object bu you forgot to add `this.lap = lap;` so you can use it as a method/property.

Should be:

```
this.start = start;
this.stop = stop;
this.reset = reset;
this.lap = lap; // this one was missing
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
this.lap = lap;
```

after the lines

```
this.start = start;
this.stop = stop;
this.reset = reset;
```